# Haskell Time Issue

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

it is my second question about haskell and i thought my algorhythm is not bad and it gives faster results in c++ and python and there is some problem at haskell it cant give me 10^25 (maybe it gives but i dont wait that much) and this question ask me that value ,please guide me to fix this guy thanks from now.

```
##Euler 169##
giveRes 0 _= 1
giveRes 1 _= 1
giveRes a x = if search a x
                then send a x
                else let res = if rem a 2 == 0
                                  then (giveRes (quot a 2) x)
                                        +
                                       (giveRes (quot a 2-1) x)
                                  else giveRes (quot a 2) x
                     in snd (head ((a,res):x))
search _ [] = False
search a (x:xs) = if a == fst x then True else search a xs
send a (x:xs) = if a == fst x then snd x else send a xs
```

code is that but its that long because it is my remembering system to shortening time but in haskell its not efficient

```
f 0 _ = 1
f a = if rem a 2 == 0
         then giveRes (quot a 2) + giveRes (quot a 2-1)
         else giveRes (quot a 2)
```

is first form of that code

Comment: As an aside--it is much easier for other people to read your Haskell code if you give explicit type signatures for your top-level functions.

Comment: I can't read the last definition, of `f` -- in the first case it has two arguments, `0` and `_`, but only one argument in the second, `a`.

Comment: i put _ accidently :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. For goodness sakes, clean up your code so people can read it. For example, rewrite `snd (head ((a,res):x)) --> res`.  Another suggestion: add type signatures.
2. Extract your common subexpressions (`quot`) into named let bindings to significantly reduce work.
3. Memoize your calls to giveRes.  This will give you the largest benefit.  If you search SO for `[haskell] memo` then you should get lots of good results.
4. Don't use a list as a set to test membership (`search`) followed by a partial function for lookup (`send`).  Instead consider using a `Map` or `HashMap` from the containers or unordered-containers libraries.